# Evaluating Lab Data in Excel

Tags: excel

Morning, I am working to review/analyze a set of lab data. It has up to 95 samples, so I am looking to automate as much as I can, but I am at a wall with this one.

Each sample has three columns; a concentration, a qualifier (which may be blank, u, or j), and a MDL. Currently the data starts in column AC, with 3 columns per sample, but for a variable number of samples.  My goal right now is to count the number of samples that have a "u" in the qualifier column AND have an MDL that is not equal to their concentration. (I tried pasting in a table, but I couldn't get it to work so apologies).

I am currently using a simple sum of `COUNTIFS` statements `"=SUM(COUNTIFS(AD5,"U",AC5,"<>"&AE5)+COUNTIFS(AG5,"U",AF5,"<>"&AH5)..."`, however I have to update the cells referenced manually which is a bit time intensive and can introduce errors. Does anyone know how I might use an offset formula or something? I figure that is my best bet since the data is uniformly setup. I just can't get it right on my end.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to reformat to a single table (probably using VBA for automation?) then create a fourth column with a logical value for the concentration == MDL test. Then use countifs like you proposed.

This can be obviously extended by creating a fifth column with the AND() test and using simple countif.

If you have samples on different columns (I get the impression because of: =SUM(COUNTIFS(AD5,"U",AC5,"<>"&AE5)+COUNTIFS(AG5,"U",AF5,"<>"&AH5)...",

and you really want to use offset, you can create a "sample count" cell for each table (located at row 1+ the maximum sample size you have in the whole book) and then use offset and countifs like you wrote. References should update automatically when copying.

If I understand correctly, you could use countifs straight up if the references are set up correctly and copy the cell, pasting it at the location I said before
(1+ the maximum sample size you have in the whole book)

Comment: Right, so what would the format be for using the offset though?

Comment: Why not this solution: "you could use countifs straight up if the references are set up correctly and copy the cell, pasting it at the location I said before (1+ the maximum sample size you have in the whole book)" ?